# Маска в input постепенное удаление содержания в placeholder. Как сделать?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка

Есть маска https://codepen.io/ivan-volyk/pen/XwRWgR

```
<div class="group-card">
        <input id="cc" type="text" name="creditcard" required="" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Номер карты</label>
```

При вводе номера карты - нули исчезают все полностью. Как реализовать, чтобы при вводе содержимого нули в placeholder исчезали постепенно?

Например: дано - 0000 0000 0000 0000; при отработке - 1230 0000 0000 0000; как сейчас 123.

Comment: Проще всего использовать плагин [`jquery inputmask`](https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.inputmask/)

Comment: `placeholder` это не маска, лучшим решением будет подключить какую-нибудь либы для масок